# EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Cannot track it down - please see crash log attached - GADObjectPrivate.m

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, crash, sigabrt

I am having trouble with one of my apps, apple rejected it due to it crashing on launch - however I cannot replicate this. I have even provided an adhoc build to another device to test and it works fine.
Anyway, they sent the crash log, and I opened it in Organiser to symbolicate.

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3311d29e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39dff97a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33120e02 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 166
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3311f52c ___forwarding___ + 388
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33076f64 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
5   diamondlite                 0x00065aec -[GADObjectPrivate loadPrivateRequest:autoRefresh:] (GADObjectPrivate.m:402)
6   diamondlite                 0x00067540 -[GADObjectPrivate loadRequest:] (GADObjectPrivate.m:827)
7   diamondlite                 0x0006501c -[GADBannerView loadRequest:] (GADBannerView.m:271)
8   diamondlite                 0x00012f40 -[GalleryViewControllerViewController viewWillAppear:] (GalleryViewControllerViewController.m:94)
9   UIKit                           0x38e94314 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 132
10  UIKit                           0x38ea08bc -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 828
11  UIKit                           0x38ea04a4 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 320
12  UIKit                           0x38e714dc -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 176
13  UIKit                           0x38e307fe -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 254
14  QuartzCore                      0x3ab04d5e -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 210
15  QuartzCore                      0x3ab048fc CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 456
16  QuartzCore                      0x3ab337a2 -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 138
17  UIKit                           0x38eda0c4 -[UIViewController window:setupWithInterfaceOrientation:] + 204
18  UIKit                           0x38ed92b0 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 3616
19  UIKit                           0x38ed8482 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 42
20  UIKit                           0x38ed840c -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 64
21  UIKit                           0x3900e17c __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke_0 + 100
22  UIKit                           0x38e96674 -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 212
23  UIKit                           0x38e963b8 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 688
24  UIKit                           0x38e95d26 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 154
25  UIKit                           0x38e8ce9e -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 366
26  UIKit                           0x38e88ae0 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 360
27  UIKit                           0x38eca1c4 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 56
28  diamondlite                 0x000112fc -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:96)
29  UIKit                           0x38e8dacc -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 248
30  UIKit                           0x38e8d656 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1186
31  UIKit                           0x38e8583e -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 694
32  UIKit                           0x38e2dc34 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1000
33  UIKit                           0x38e2d6c8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
34  UIKit                           0x38e2d116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
35  GraphicsServices                0x365a959e _PurpleEventCallback + 586
36  GraphicsServices                0x365a91ce PurpleEventCallback + 30
37  CoreFoundation                  0x330f216e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
38  CoreFoundation                  0x330f2112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
39  CoreFoundation                  0x330f0f94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
40  CoreFoundation                  0x33063eb8 0x3305b000 + 36536
41  CoreFoundation                  0x33063d44 0x3305b000 + 36164
42  UIKit                           0x38e84478 0x38e2a000 + 369784
43  UIKit                           0x38e812f4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
44  diamondlite                 0x00010dc2 main (main.m:16)
45  diamondlite                 0x00010d5c start + 36


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32047350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39d9e11e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39dda96e abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37fa7d4a abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37fa4ff4 default_terminate() + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39dffa74 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37fa5078 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37fa5110 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37fa6594 __cxa_rethrow + 84
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39dff9cc objc_exception_rethrow + 8
10  CoreFoundation                  0x33063f1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
11  CoreFoundation                  0x33063d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
12  UIKit                           0x38e84478 -[UIApplication _run] + 664
13  UIKit                           0x38e812f4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
14  diamondlite                 0x00010dc2 main (main.m:16)
15  diamondlite                 0x00010d5c start + 36
```

At the end it also says;

```
Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3cbef534
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3cbefb88      r6: 0x1dd82414      r7: 0x2fdf2a14
    r8: 0x1dd823f0    r9: 0x00000300     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x000b55de
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdf2a08      lr: 0x39d9e123      pc: 0x32047350
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

I just have no idea what is causing the problem? Because I cannot replicate it on my devices which makes it even harder - I hope someone can help?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: What's happening at line 402 of this file: GADObjectPrivate.m?  (The crash says you're calling a method that doesn't exist for the object you're calling it on.)

Comment: Hi, I can't even find that file in my code... :/ The GAD files are from GoogleAdMobAdsSDKiOS-6.2.1 but the files in that folder, none of them are called GADObjectPrivate.m

Comment: How about starting with `GalleryViewControllerViewController.m:94` and working down from there to see what it calls and so on?

Comment: `if (![[InAppRageIAPHelper sharedHelper].purchasedProducts containsObject:@"com.adamsapps.diamondslite.pro"]
            && ![[InAppRageIAPHelper sharedHelper].purchasedProducts containsObject:@"com.adamsapps.diamondslitehd.pro"]) {
            
 upgradeButton.hidden = NO;
            [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
        }else{
            upgradeButton.hidden = YES;
}
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  if ([self.tblData count] > ([self.objScrollView.subviews count]-2)) {
[self addViews];
}
[self rearrangeViews:0];
}`

Comment: That makes sense since `[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];` matches the next stack frame.  I'm not familiar with the GAD classes so I can't guess what they require.  You might want to add some reference to them in your tags or in the title of your question to see if you can attract someone who has that experience.

Comment: Thanks Phillip, it would seem it is something in the advertisements, as the pro version of my app does not crash and has no advertisements, although I have used the same code in many of my apps without issue, it's very strange!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was moving the Admob banner request into the ViewDidAppear section, oddly that seemed to fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, but something slightly different caused it. Whenever I ran the app from XCode it worked perfectly fine, but the Appstore kindly continued to rejected it.

Unfortunately they where right, and the app did crash on launch with **EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000**.

Only after I finally realised that the Archive build uses different build settings to the debug build, was I able to reproduce it.

My mistake was that I had renamed my storyboard and the dev still picked up a version of it but the archive build did not.

Lesson learnt from this:

- Always create an archive build, which you distribute using an adhoc
  distribution in the organiser ( do not use you Distribution signing
  entity to sign it.)
- Drag the IPA file it creates to your iTunes
- Remove the app from your device
- Deploy the new app created by the IPA to your device.

You are now running the Actual build that will be sent to Appstore, and should be able to reproduce some of those nasty errors.

Answer (score 0):

this issue is related about lacking of -ObjC linker flag.

So, add linker flag -objC both debug and release (the profile that you use for archive)

You can also test your release binary with adhoc profile.