# App just approved crashes on iPad

Tags: iphone, sqlite, logging, sdk, crash

Hi I have an App on the AppStore, I made an update which is working fine on simulator and my iPad 4 so I sent to AppStore for publishing. The App uses a Sqlite Database that is updated in this version.
I got message App is ok and approved by Apple Ready to Sale, so I downloaded the App on my iPad to see it working and it just crash in Navigation Controller.

I wonder if Apple people do not get the App crash,could you give me some advice on how I can solve this problem?

thanks this is crash log from Organizer

```
    Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-03-31 17:45:48.047 +0200
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.2 (10B146)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                0x323bc3e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib               0x3a23c95e objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                0x323bff2c -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 180
3   CoreFoundation                0x323be648 ___forwarding___ + 388
4   CoreFoundation                0x32316204 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
5   APP                       0x0010ec28 -[GADObjectPrivate loadPrivateRequest:autoRefresh:] (GADObjectPrivate.m:412)
6   APP                       0x00110988 -[GADObjectPrivate loadRequest:] (GADObjectPrivate.m:878)
7   APP                       0x0010e108 -[GADBannerView loadRequest:] (GADBannerView.m:267)
8   APP                       0x000ea918 -[ElementDetail viewDidLoad] (ElementDetail.m:61)
9   UIKit                         0x341ea574 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 360
10  UIKit                         0x3423f1f2 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 22
11  UIKit                         0x3423f138 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 24
12  UIKit                         0x3423f01c -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 28
13  UIKit                         0x3423ef48 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 268
14  UIKit                         0x3423e694 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 60
15  UIKit                         0x3423e57c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 320
16  UIKit                         0x3422cb56 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 854
17  UIKit                         0x3422c7f6 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 34
18  APP                       0x000e6982 -[CardsViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (CardsViewController.m:323)
19  UIKit                         0x3428d318 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 872
20  UIKit                         0x3430fda4 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 152
21  Foundation                    0x32ccb652 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 446
22  CoreFoundation                0x32391852 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 10
23  CoreFoundation                0x323914fe __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 270
24  CoreFoundation                0x32390172 __CFRunLoopRun + 1226
25  CoreFoundation                0x32303238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
26  CoreFoundation                0x323030c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
27  GraphicsServices              0x35ebd336 GSEventRunModal + 70
28  UIKit                         0x3421f2b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
29  APP                      0x000e31ae main (main.m:14)
30  libdyld.dylib                 0x3a669b1c start + 0
```

Comment: just go through [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports) i hope you will find some way out.

Comment: I answered this in this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/a/19175602/2110320
It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484084/exc-crash-sigabrt-cannot-track-it-down-please-see-crash-log-attached-gadob), you should place your `-loadRequest:` call in `viewWillAppear`, not `viewDidLoad`.

It doesn't appear that Google releases the source to `GADObjectPrivate`, so it's difficult to verify if or why this works.

Comment: what really drives me crazy is that on my device I do not get any errors, app is approved by Apple so it should not crash, but crashes after downloaded from AppStore only ..

Comment: I made the changes and see it again to Apple, the app got approved again, I downloaded and it crashes again

Comment: new crash log Last 2   CoreFoundation                  0x323bff2c -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 180
3   CoreFoundation                  0x323be648 ___forwarding___ + 388
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32316204 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
5   APP                         0x0010ac28 0xde000 + 183336
6   APP                         0x0010c988 0xde000 + 190856
7   APP                         0x0010a108 0xde000 + 180488
8   UIKit                           0x342322f0 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 132